# A basic question about $\operatorname{supp}f$ (support of f).

Tags: measure-theory, fourier-analysis, distribution-theory, lp-spaces

Is it true that $\operatorname{supp}f$ is the complement of the biggest open set where $f=0
$?

Here $\operatorname{supp}f=$ {$x\in \Bbb R^n  ; f(x)\not=0$} and $f\in C$ (collection of continuous maps from $\Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$)

Comment: The support is not what you write after "Here".

Comment: Usually, the topological support is defined to be $\overline{\{x\;;\; f(x)\neq 0\}}$. It is closed.

Comment: And yes, if you take the closure I mentioned above as your definition, it is the complement of the union of all open sets on which $f$ vanishes. Just because the closure of $\{x\;;\;f(x)\neq 0\}$ is the intersection of all closed sets that contain it.

Comment: @Did, you are right. Actually the definition that I supposed is not true. The question that i raised is obvious as supp⁡f is the closure of the set where f does not vanish. I'm so sorry. :P Should I delete this question from stack exchange?

Comment: @SaraTancredi A question should not be deleted after other users put an effort into answering it. You can [edit] it to correct whatever mistakes were made in the formulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your question is tagged $L^p$-spaces (which are spaces of equivalence classes of functions), one should distinguish between

- Support of a function $f$, which is the complement of the largest open set on which $f$ is zero identically.
- Support of an equivalence class $f\in L^p$, which is  the complement of the largest open set on which (every representative of) $f$ is zero almost everywhere.

In first case, the  existence of largest such open set follows by taking the union of all open sets that qualify. In the second case one has to be more careful: assume that there is a countable base of the topology and take the union of all base elements that meet the requirement.

The second notion of support is sometimes called *essential support*, I think.

Comment: @julien I mostly had the second case in mind, where uncountable unions are problematic. Edited to clarify.

Comment: I googled and I am surprised to see that the term "essential support" does not seem to be widely spread. Here is a [related thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/80128/lp-function-that-has-no-compact-support).

Comment: "Essential support" - me too heard it first time. 
Actually everything is new for me. I just completed a basic course on measure theory and now I am heading towards little serious kind of analysis. Thank you @75064 and Julien for your support.